# Fail to build Boost 1.62.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

I'm trying to build Boost 1.62.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. However,

```
error: Name clash for '<pstage/lib>libboost_atomic.so.1.62.0'
error: 
error: Tried to build the target twice, with property sets having 
error: these incompatible properties:
error: 
error:     -  <debug-symbols>on <inlining>off <optimization>off <runtime-debugging>on <variant>debug
error:     -  <debug-symbols>off <define>NDEBUG <inlining>full <optimization>speed <runtime-debugging>off <variant>release
error: 
error: Please make sure to have consistent requirements for these 
error: properties everywhere in your project, especially for install
error: targets.
```

this error occurred.

Full Error Log:
http://pastebin.com/RusYrwvw

To avoid this, I tried to use `--without-xxxxx` however, it has no effect.

```
$ uname -a
Linux yumetodo-desktop 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609
```

How should I do to resolve?

Comment: Sounds to me like a problem with your compiler installation, or something on that order. A simple `./boostrap`, `./b2` `sudo b2 install` worked fine for me.

Comment: ``./b2 threading=multi address-model=64 architecture=x86 -j 4 -s BZIP2_SOURCE=~/ダウンロード/bzip2-1.0.6 cxxflags="-std=c++14"`` work fine!
But what is the cause?

Comment: ``variant=debug,release link=shared runtime-link=shared `` is broken...?